# Prevent referencing built in members of Object

Tags: javascript, firefox

When creating a new object, you are able to reference any member of the [object class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). For example:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj["watch"];  //returns the watch() function of Object
```

Is there a way to override this default behavior so that obj["watch"] returns undefined instead? Note that I only see this behavior in Firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since EcmaScript 5.1, you can generate objects without a prototype (and without `Object.protoype`) [this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var empty = Object.create(null);
empty.watch; // undefined
```

You will need the native function, the simple polyfill that utilizes `new` is not capable of doing this. See also [this docs section of es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim#shams).

> Note that I only see this behavior in Firefox

That's because [`watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) is a non-standard FF extension. You should be able to obtain the [standard properties](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4) in other browsers as well, though.